# прогноз погоды openweathermap

Tags: python, openweathermap

снова вопрос от новичка python. для моего проекта требуется прогноз погоды со среднесуточными значениями на три дня. порывшись в интернете, наткнулась на пример использования openweathermap.org, но бесплатная подписка дает прогноз погоды на 5 дней и на каждые три часа.вопрос в следующем,подскажите как изменить,чтобы выводилась погода на три даты,выбранные пользователем, и значения погоды были не по часам,а среднесуточными. или может есть другие api и примеры,где показано как это делается.
если в параметрах прописать cnt=3,выводится просто три записи

```
import requests
city_id = 57
appid = ""
try:  
    res = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast",params={'id': city_id, 'units': 'metric','cnt':'3','lang': 'ru', 'APPID': appid})
    data = res.json()
    for i in data['list']:
        print( i['dt_txt'], '{0:+3.0f}'.format(i['main']['temp']),i['main']['pressure'],i['main']['humidity'],i['wind']['speed'])
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception (forecast):", e)
    pass
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос то не по питону, и тем более не по pyqt5, а по openweathermap. Смотрите в документацию openweathermap

Comment: С openweathermap получаем записи с интервалом в три часа. 8 записей в сутки. Их то и надо обработать, чтобы получить среднесуточную температуру. Это чистая математика и легко реализуемая.